# Static List Showing as Null

Tags: c#

I have a static class called Constants.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string sampleString= "";
    public static List<int> sampleList= new List<int> {1,2,3};
}
```

If I call my static list outside:
`Constants.sampleList` it gives me a **null exception** but `Constants.sampleString` can be called *with no problem*.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you, please, provide the relevant code (i.e. error repoducing)?

Comment: Side note: adding `readonly` i.e. `public static readonly List<int> sampleList= new List<int> {1,2,3};` will allow you to *maniputale* with the list (e.g. `Constants.sampleList.Add(4)`), but prevent you to assing `null` to it

Comment: Is the list is actually as shown, that is an integer list and not list of class?

Comment: If you make a search in your entire solution for "samleList" I bet you will have a line that sets it to null... On another hand, making it readonly will generate a compiler error and you will find where the null asignation comes from.

Comment: May you add a setter for this list and add a little test about null just to find what is setting it to null.

Comment: Please add the line that throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same case as ours but we have a class that access the key from the config

```
string sampleString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SampleString"]
```

Sample string was deleted from our web.config due to some merging issues. Error for null pointer happens when you access any of the variables in the class bellow the variable.

Adding the key in the config fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Constants.sampleList.Contains(1));
}

public static class Constants
{
    public static string sampleString= "";
    public static List<int> sampleList= new List<int> {1,2,3};
}
```

I get `True` on the Console. You need to provide the code which demonstrates the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `readonly` keyword to your method. The method can only be instantiated inside constructor or  at the property declaration phase.

```
public static readonly List<int> sampleList= new List<int> {1,2,3};
```

If you ever try to reinitialize or make new assignment to `sampleList`, C# compiler will give you compiler error.

Yet better to use Property

```
public static readonly List<int> SampleList {get; set;} = new List<int> {1,2,3};
```

Comment: wourld it be possible to reproduce the issue? because it doesn't make sense

Comment: If we implement *property* we have to prevent assigning `null` to it: in your current code `Constants.SampleList = null;` is still possible. We can either drop `set` at all or implement it with `value` validation

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i search for all reference for the property only reading the value is retrieved and no assigning. Im dumbfounded as well how this could happen.

Comment: @TheProvost: you have a *stack trace* (i.e. sequence of calls which lead to the error) of the exception, please, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no miracles, and if `sampleList` is `null` (and you have *exception thrown*) then you asign `null` to it somewhere.
Try not to *expose* `public` *fields* which makes `Constants` vulnerable:

```
  public static class Constants
  {
      public static string sampleString = "";
      public static List<int> sampleList = new List<int> {1,2,3};
  }

  ...

  Constants.sampleList = null;   // We can easly assign null

  ...

  Constants.sampleList.Add(123); // <- And have an unxpected exception
```

But either turn them into *properties*:

```
  public static class Constants
  {
      private static string s_SampleString = "";
      private static List<int> s_SampleList = new List<int> {1,2,3}; 

      public static string sampleString {
        get {return s_SampleString;}
        set {s_SampleString = value ?? "";}
      }

      public static List<int> sampleList {
        get {return s_SampleList;}
        // I doubt you actually want set here
        set {s_SampleList = value ?? new List<int>();}  
      }
  }
```

Or, at least, mark the field(s) as `readonly` (you can assign them once only):

```
  public static class Constants
  {
      private static string s_SampleString = "";

      public static string sampleString {
        get {return s_SampleString;}
        set {s_SampleString = value ?? "";}
      }

      // Manipulate with me, but not reassign
      public static readonly List<int> sampleList = new List<int> {1,2,3}; 
  }
```

In either case you still can manipulate with the list:

```
  Constants.sampleList.Add(4);
  Constants.sampleList.RemoveAt(0);
```

But you are protected from assigning `null` to the list: either empty list will be assigned (code with property) or you'll have compile time error (code with `readonly`)

Comment: @TheProvost: could you provide the code which throws the exception, please?

Comment: Constants.sampleList.Contains(1) gives a null exception. Even created a new entire list and still same issue.

Comment: @TheProvost: Time to debug: please, put *break points* on  `sampleList` *property* `set` and `get`. Let's inspect what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was defining a `private static readonly Dictionary<byte, string>` inside a struct to hold predefined constants. This normally would work fine, however I also had defined a MinValue within my struct to represent the minimum value of a piece of data. When done this way the static dictionary was uninitialized unless defined above the static MinValue property. I'm probably asking a little too much of the compiler and should restructure it instead.

It was hard to diagnose in a large struct as I didn't expect that behavior with C#. Example to reproduce:

```cs
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string Str;

    public static readonly MyStruct MinValue = new MyStruct(0);

    public MyStruct(byte val)
    {
        Str = _predefinedValues[val]; // null reference exception
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<byte, string> _predefinedValues = new Dictionary<byte, string>()
    {
        {0x00, "test 1"},
        {0x01, "test 2"},
        {0x02, "test 3"},
    };

}
```

The solution here is twofold:

1. to not call any constructors on the struct and explicitly set each field without accessing `_predefinedValues` list.
2. Alternatively, moving the list up above the MinValue field declaration actually does fix it as well (strange right?)

I suspect something weird happens on the stack when trying to allocate this and it's probably a weird thing to do.

Comment: Your "example to reproduce" does not reproduce the claimed behavior. Indeed, if it did, the framework would be broken, because it would violate the language specification, which _requires_ the static constructor (where the static field init is done) to be executed _prior_ to the access of any method or field of the class. Never mind that this post in no way answers the question that was asked, it's not even accurate as a standalone.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are correct, I neglected to test my sample and it only solved the problem in my original code. I've updated the sample to reflect the actual cause of the issue when defining the struct. My original was very complex, and the debugger didn't make it easy to find. It is however different than the original question, I got here trying to find the cause of this somewhat similar issue.

Comment: _"I'm probably asking a little too much of the compiler and should restructure it instead."_ -- well, especially since the language specification clearly says it must _not_ do that. Static field initialization is done in lexical order, by design. Ironically, your "twofold" solution ignores what is considered the _correct_ means of dealing with this sort of thing, which is to declare a static constructor and explicitly initialize the things you need initialized in some order other than the predefined one.

Comment: reposted as a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344696/c-sharp-struct-definition-fields-that-access-static-members-result-in-nullref